# How to use flutter plugins on Native code

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-add-to-app

I'm trying to use a flutter library that I developed on native code. It uses [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus). However, for certain plugins, you need to update your `build.gradle` dependencies ([Managing plugins and dependencies in add-to-app](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/android/plugin-setup#b-plugins-needing-project-edits)) I believe this package is one such example, however I don't know what to add on my `build.gradle` or where to look for help.

When I use `FlutterFragment` on Android, the app runs, but it gives me the `MissingPluginException` error.

Any thoughts on how to solve this / find the deps I need?

Thanks in advance for helping.